# Getting error while running python manage.py runserver command

Tags: django, python-3.x

I followed the simple steps of creating Django project using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/

I have created project mysite, it has got manage.py & child folder named mysite which has *init*.py, settings.py, urls.py and wsgi.py.

Now, when I run server command python manage.py runserver, I get below error, its coming from exception part of manage.py file

**ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget t
o activate a virtual environment?**

I have installed python, django, pip in below path & also set PATH: Env variables
C:\Users\jeevan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\mysite

Comment: Did you create your site within the Lib\site-packages? because I don't think you should do that. Just create your project outside the Python folder.

Comment: yes, I created my project "mysite" under site-packages, do you suggest it to create at python folder level? C:\Users\jeevan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36?

Comment: I suggest you create it outside of `appdata`

Comment: When I try to create it outside of appdata, i get error django-admin is not recognized as the name of cmdlet. Which means Django commands are supported where its installed & not outside. Need to find some other way

Comment: then you've installed django the wrong way, because it should be able to work outside the `appdata`